# What does "SSC WriteBack" mean

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, lsi, broadcom

When I dump LSI RAID 9260-8i configuration by:

```
/storcli /c0 show all
```

the `Supported VD Operations` section looks like:

```
Read Policy = Yes
Write Policy = Yes
IO Policy = Yes
Access Policy = Yes
Disk Cache Policy = Yes
Reconstruction = Yes
Deny Locate = No
Deny CC = No
Allow Ctrl Encryption = No
Enable LDBBM = Yes
Support FastPath = Yes
Performance Metrics = Yes
Power Savings = No
Support Powersave Max With Cache = No
Support Breakmirror = No
Support SSC WriteBack = Yes
Support SSC Association = Yes
Support VD Hide = No
Support VD Cachebypass = No
Support VD discardCacheDuringLDDelete = No
```

what does the `SSC WriteBack` expression there mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the **S**olid **S**tate **C**ache disk policy for LSI CacheCade 2.0.
When using CacheCade 2.0, you can set the cache device as writethrough (similar to how CacheCade 1.0 worked) or writeback (to increase random write performance).

Comment: It makes a perfect sense, as on some RAIDs we have CacheCade installed and on some not, and it is set to `Yes` only on these RAIDs we have this feature installed. Thanks!